# Does libgdx play nice without eclipse?

Tags: android, libgdx

I've only done small bit of work with android and I'm not a huge fan of Eclipse. I've been working on the command-line with Ant build scripts. Will libgdx play nice with a text editor/command-line environment? I can't seem to find any documentation online--everybody seems to be using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nothing specific here.

I'm using libgdx with `IntelliJ IDEA` and pretty happy with it.
It's just a matter of setting the right `PATH` and `CLASSPATH`.